# jQuery window.on hashchnage not working on same hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery window.on hashchnage not working on the same hash

Using the below code:

```
 function addMargin() {
    let header = $('.header__wrapper').outerHeight();
    let headerHeight = $('body').hasClass('logged--in') ? header + 80 : header;
    window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset - headerHeight);
  }
```

**js**

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', addMargin, false);
```

**jquery**

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    addMargin();
  });
```

How can I make hash works if a user clicks on the same hash?

Comment: If the hash is the same, then the `hashchange` event will not be fired. What if you turn the issue on its head, and invoke `addMargin()` on whatever event that is causing the hashchange itself?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event

The Event `hashchange` is only fired, when the hash really changes. When it stays them same nothing happens.

You need to find a different way to add your eventhandler to the user click event.